# Распарсить url

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Привет всем.
Пытаюсь распарсить URL, не немного не выходит это. Я только учусь парсить, поэтому не ругайтесь.

mydomain.ru/stat.php?url=domain.com

Там вот такой код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<url>domain.com</url>
<status>ok</status>
<domain>domain.com</domain>
<stat>644959</stat>
<keywords>113</keywords>
<costs>321</costs>
</data>
```

Comment: Любым XML-парсером, хоть DOM (контента мало), хоть SAX.

Comment: Можно пример?
Хотябы вывести, domain, url

Answer (score 1):

Есть два варианта, юзнуть preg_match(), либо simplexml, что указал Bullet777

```
$xmlstr = file_get_contents("mydomain.ru/stat.php?url=domain.com");
$rsl = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
var_dump($rsl);
```